# How to change shell to custom shell?

Tags: linux, shell

So, I have made a little shell script in PHP with some basics functions (ls, cat, etc..) and I'd like to use it as my default shell.

But since I don't want to do a mistake, I have some questions: If I change the /etc/passwd file and say that my shell is now /bash/myshell.php, will it work? Does the file need to be in /bin, or would something like /Downloads/myscript.php work?

I'm running Debian 8

Comment: It should work, but the most simple way to see it, it is to add a new user and to do your attempts with the new user. (keep always at least one user with a _standard_ shell). Check the attributes of, for example, `/bin/bash` with the new one (` /bash/myshell.php`), and _who_ you will be in your shell...

Answer (score 0):

Your new shell should be listed in 
/etc/shells (by root). Users can then use chsh to change shell. 
You can store executables in /bin, on other filesystems that depends on the mount options.